# Using Stripe Payments With Angular/Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I'm currently having a problem with how to securely implement payments with angular & firstore.

Currently

- Items are displayed to the user from a firestore collection.
- User buys item and is redirected to a stripe checkout.
- On the backend webhook listens for checkout.session.completed and saves the order to firestore collection on completion.

My understanding is that with Firestore being accessible to anyone who has access to the webpage, a visitor could easily just write their own order to the collection & even with restricting customers to being logged in as they are directly interacting with the orders collection they do need to be able to update it without maliciously updsting it.

My question: can I mitigate this with security rules alone for example is it possible to pass a secret key with each order & not allowing documents to be written if the key doesn't match. If not are their other options or will I have to restructure the whole app?

Comment: This is not Stripe-specific, and relates primarily to manage authentication with firestore. You should ensure that your source of truth is only updated with authenticated request eg from Stripe webhooks known to be from Stripe by verifying signatures: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures

Comment: I have implemented the signature check in the webhook which is why I can be certain any calls to firestore from within the webhook are valid. I'm trying to figure out how to secure my firestore collection so that only calls to write from the webhook are allowed.

Comment: So I believe i was able to achieve this relatively easily  using the firebase-admin sdk, service-accounts & blocking write access in the security rules.